# How to extract the misclassified labels from evaluating the performance of the model (BinaryClassificationEvaluator)?

Tags: confusion-matrix, sentence-transformers

I am currently using sentence transformers to find the similarity between 2 sentences and I have a labelled data of either 1 or 0 (similar, not similar). After training my own model, I can evaluate the model performance on a dev/test dataset as shown below.

```
dev_samples = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    input_example = InputExample(texts=[row['Sent_1'], row['Sent_2']], label=row['Label_0_1'])
    dev_samples.append(input_example)    

model = SentenceTransformer(bi_encoder_model_save_path)
dev_evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator.from_input_examples(dev_samples, name="dev_sample")

# CSV file with performance result is exported in the model folder
dev_evaluator(model, output_path=f'''{cwd}''')
```

In the above example, I am using `BinaryClassificationEvaluator.from_input_examples(dev_samples, name="dev_sample")`

The result is saved to an csv file with specific columns such as:
[image: Result from evaluation]

*How can I identify or extract the misclassified labels into a confusion matrix? Should I calculate the score using `encode()` of each input example and identify if the score is > 50, it is similar (1) and less, it is non-similar (0)*

[https://www.sbert.net/docs/usage/semantic_textual_similarity.html](https://Semantic%20textual%20similarity)

[Github Code](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/examples/training/sts/training_stsbenchmark_continue_training.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from "[Semantic Textual Similarity](https://www.sbert.net/docs/usage/semantic_textual_similarity.html)", you would need to compare the predicted labels against the true labels for each example in your development (dev) dataset.
The [`BinaryClassificationEvaluator`](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/e0d93bb377eca9e0c94da436f3f35c336e9c109d/sentence_transformers/evaluation/BinaryClassificationEvaluator.py#L15) does not directly output misclassified examples (as illustrated by [`UKPLab/sentence-transformers` issue 1516](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/issues/1516)), so you will need to manually calculate the predictions using the `encode()` method and then compare these predictions to the true labels.

- The `encode()` method will encode both sentences in each `InputExample`, then calculate the similarity score. The similarity can be calculated using the [cosine similarity](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/e0d93bb377eca9e0c94da436f3f35c336e9c109d/sentence_transformers/util.py#L22) between the embeddings of the two sentences.
- Based on the similarity score, determine the predicted label. You mentioned using a threshold of 50% (or 0.5 in a normalized [0, 1] scale if your similarity scores are normalized). Labels above this threshold can be considered similar (1), and below it, not similar (0).
- For each `InputExample`, compare the predicted label to the true label (the `label` attribute of `InputExample`).
  Based on the comparison, tally the true positives, false positives, true negatives, and false negatives to construct a confusion matrix.

As an example:

```py
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util
import numpy as np

# Assume model is already loaded
model = SentenceTransformer(bi_encoder_model_save_path)

# Encode sentences and calculate similarity scores
predictions = []
for example in dev_samples:
    embeddings = model.encode(example.texts)
    similarity_score = util.pytorch_cos_sim(embeddings[0], embeddings[1])
    predicted_label = 1 if similarity_score >= 0.5 else 0
    predictions.append((predicted_label, example.label))

# Construct a confusion matrix
true_positives = sum(1 for pred, true in predictions if pred == true == 1)
false_positives = sum(1 for pred, true in predictions if pred == 1 and true == 0)
true_negatives = sum(1 for pred, true in predictions if pred == true == 0)
false_negatives = sum(1 for pred, true in predictions if pred == 0 and true == 1)

confusion_matrix = np.array([[true_positives, false_positives],
                             [false_negatives, true_negatives]])

print("Confusion Matrix:")
print(confusion_matrix)
```

Comment: I did use the encode to find the cosine similarity and threshold. Thanks